# How To Delete Specific Row in Table?

Tags: reactjs

I want to delete a row in React. It deletes but it doesn't render until I refresh the page. I want it to delete without need to refresh.

My react code:

```
deleteFromDb(row_id) {
    fetch('/deleteNotes', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({id: row_id}),
    }).then(res => res.json()).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  })
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
  }) 
  
  }
```

Comment: If on click of delete button if u are sending API call to delete record. Need to recall get list of rows API on success of delete which will show correct data in db.

Comment: Why do you need `Object.values(this.state.myNotesArray)`? Could you make a codesandbox with sample data?

Comment: I just tried to do it like that because it worked when I was filling my table. It is array of objects so filter works with array and that's why it gives error. My code is really long so that's why I didn't post

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter it like this, given `myNotesArray` is an array of "todo" objects and `row_id` is the index of `todo` in the array:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  myNotesArray: prevState.myNotesArray.filter((todo, i) => i !== row_id)
}));
```

Or like this if "todo"s actually have their own `id`s

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  myNotesArray: prevState.myNotesArray.filter(todo => todo.id !== row_id)
}));
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to change my code. I already write it like yours but it gave "prevState.myNotesArray.filter is not a function" error so I changed it like my code but it still not working

Comment: Please share the structure of state and actual code in question

Comment: I shared the necessary parts